# print array in method in vue.js

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, vue.js, while-loop

I am very new to vue and I wanted to play around with methods a little. What I wanted to try was printing out an array of Strings and this is the method I tried to use:

```
printStringArray(objectWithArray) {
      i = 0;
      s = '';

      while(i < objectWithArray.stringArray.length) {
        s = objectWithArray.stringArray[i] + s,
      }; 
      return  s;
    },
```

But I get errors because of i and s. I tried a few things but it always either says I didn't define or them or I defined them but didn't use them. Any ideas? I looked at some posts that used working code but if I used that code to see my mistake in comparisons, I get the same erros. I feel like it's very simple but I can't find anything on it.

Comment: Is there a specific reason you're not using a `forEach` loop? It's usually easier for iterating through arrays.

Comment: Because I wanted to use a while-loop before I try forEach-loops.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following method:

```js
let array = [1, 2, 3, 4];
function printArrayElements(array){
    array.forEach(element => console.log(element))
}

printArrayElements(array);
```

You can achieve that using the `while` loop as well:

```js
let array = [1, 2, 3, 4]
function printArrayElement(array){
    let index = 0;
    while (index < array.length){
        console.log(array[index]);
        index +=1;
    }
}

printArrayElement(array);
```

Comment: Oh, that was good! With let they finally accepted my s as defined AND used. Perfect thanks! I knew it was something super small.. :)

Comment: In  while loop example change the console.log(array[a]);  to console.log(array[index]);

Comment: Thanks, I replaced it with the correct argument name @Makesh

Answer (score 1):

It's more about javascript than it is vue. To the point:

You have a function called `toString` that does that for you.
**Here's a snippet:**

```
const stuff = [0, 1, "Apple", "Mango"];
const x = fruits.toString();
console.log(x);
```

Answer (score 1):

You've the possibility to use the join method and show the items separated by space :

```
printStringArray(objectWithArray) {
      let joined=objectWithArray.join(" ");
      console.log(joined)
     return joined;
    },
```

Comment: So many good answers! I love this one! I didn't know I could do that :)

Comment: you're welcome, thanks to giving me my first 10 points, you also use any separator in `join` method like `join("/")`